# Promise { <pending> } error while calling async function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js

This is my async function:

```
/**
 * @param {String} user 
 * @param {String} pass
 */
async function checkInfo(user, pass){
let client = new MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/', {useNewUrlParser:true});
try {
        client = await client.connect();
        const db = client.db('user');
        const users = db.collection("user");
        const infos = await users.find({ username: user, password: pass}).toArray();
        if(infos.length != 0){
        return true;
        }else{
        return false;
        }
    } 
    catch (error) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And I call this function at POST method at the backend (Server).It writes Promise {  } at terminal.

Comment: ALL `async` functions return a promise.  The caller has to use `.then()` or `await` to get the value out of the promise.  That's how `async` functions work.

Comment: @jfriend00 when i use await it writes that await is only valid in async function. i call this function at non-async function(when i get GET request)

Comment: Yes, that's how `await` works.  You can either make that containing function be `async` so you can use `await` there or you can use `.then()` on the promise.  If you showed that part of the code, we could  show you directly how to do it. But, without that code, this is just a theoretical discussion.

Comment: @jfriend00 https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vTIjbgt6ffcW3k6dtM4hcIPPLjvjQFeLpqlTawpfDAGWLFFCn_Xx-hmsg-_wvOF053ZMgyxgbAmMaRR/pub

Comment: The way stackoverflow works, please paste your code into your question as text and format it appropriately as code.  This is for a bunch of reasons, including the fact that external links tend to disappear or change over time wrecking the use of this question as a longer term reference for others (which is part of stackoverflow's mission).

Comment: @jfriend00 i found the way: i just wrote async at the parent -> parent function. it was anonym function)) thank you for your reply

Comment: Glad it worked.  Please include all relevant code in your question for next time and you will get faster and more accurate answers.